# How do you change your craigslist verification phone number?

Tags: craigslist

A friend of mine uses craigslist, and his phone number recently changed. Now craigslist tries to do the phone verification, but they use the old phone number. Is there any way to change the phone number they use other than to create a new account?

Answer (score 1):

It requires phoning them to change it:

Cragislist.com Contact Info

Toll Free Number: 1-800-664-0633

Comment: Calling Craiglist at that number is a Kafkaesque joke. There are no options corresponding to this sort of inquiry, and in fact all options other than saying you are calling from the police simply direct you to the website or ask you to contact them by email. As far as I can tell there is NO phone assistance whatsoever available via that number.

Answer (score 1):

You change your password and it resets it